# IntelliJ got out of memory after installing Tortoise SVN 64bit on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn, 64-bit, intellij-idea

IntelliJ 8.1 (also tried 9) was working fine without Tortoise SVN, but after I installed Tortoise SVN 64bit on Windows 7, I'm getting out of memory every time I launch IntelliJ.

Increasing VM memory allocation doesn't work no matter how much I increase.

I googled and found few information about this particular issue, has anyone got the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tortoise SVN installation should not affect IDEA in any way. I have the same configuration (Windows 7, 64-bit, Tortoise SVN) and IDEA works fine. IDEA doesn't use command line SVN, it has Java implementation of SVN protocol via SvnKit library.

The only thing that can somehow affect IDEA is the system wide Subversion configuration file (`c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config`). Check that there are no weird settings in it or try to configure IDEA to use a different Subversion configuration directory.

Also check if this problem is reproducible in IDEA 10.5.x.

Comment: The problem still persists after I changed the SVN config folder. I'm sure it is something to do with Tortoise SVN client I just installed. I checked out the code using it, then open the project from within IntelliJ. I just tried checkout out the code from within IntelliJ directly, and it is ok.

Comment: Adding -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in idea.exe.vmoptions should produce hprof memory snapshot on OOM that you can upload to our FTP: ftp://intellij.net/.uploads/ so that we can investigate this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Seems it was caused by TortoiseSVN upgrading Subversion working copy format to 1.7 (it asked me to do so), while IDEA is probably only able to work properly with 1.6 (since it's the highest version number it offers me when I checkout a new project). I use IDEA 9.0.2 BTW.

I solved this by checking out the project (using IDEA) into a new folder and not letting TortoiseSVN to upgrade working copy version. If you have any uncommited changes in the old folder you'd probably have to either commit them first via TortoiseSVN and then perform SVN update on the new folder or to copy them into a new directory by hand.

Comment: thanks man:) we have only 9.0.2 license here and it works exactly this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... It is causing by SVN... If u checkout the code into a folder and use that folder for intellij, it throws "out of memory" exception. Copy the folder that u checkedout into another folder and try to open the project through that folder.. and it works!!!!! Atleast It worked for me....  Good luck guys..